# Storing the returned values of calling a function in a loop in a list

Tags: python, loops, return-value

I have two functions:

1. `SendMail(to, f_name, table )` - it sends a mail `to` the recipient using smtplib. Code snippet:

   ```
   def SendMail(to, f_name, table )
       # ...

       server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
       server.ehlo()
       server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
       print("Type 'Y' to send the mail! ")
       text = input(">")
       if text.lower() == "y":
           #print("Sending mail")
           server.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
           print("Mail sent to "+ first_name)
           server.close()
           status = 'success'
           return status
       else:
           print("Mail NOT sent to " + first_name)
           status = 'fail'
           return status
   ```
2. `MailLoop()`: I have a list of people that I'm sending a customised mail to.

   ```
   def MailLoop():
       for owner in owner_list:
           to = 'somemailaddress'
           f_name = 'somefirstname'
           table = 'sometable'
           SendMail(to, f_name, table)
   ```

How can I pass the value of `status` that is returned from the `SendMail(to, f_name, table )` function after each iteration to the outer `MailLoop()` function?

I would like to store the status of each iteration in a list so that I can see and print the result after the `MailLoop()` function is finished.

Comment: You *are* returning the value, you just need to assign it to a variable in `MailLoop` (or append it to a list).

Comment: for example `results = []` before the loop then `results.append(SendMail(...))` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a list from MailLoop:

```
def MailLoop():
    statuses = []
    for owner in owner_list:
        to = 'someemailaddress'
        f_name = 'somefirstname'
        table = 'sometable'
        statuses.append(SendMail(to, f_name, table))
    return statuses
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you could either append the result to a list or make it a generator.

Example for generator:

```
def MailLoop():
    for owner in owner_list:
        to = 'somemailaddress'
        f_name = 'somefirstname'
        table = 'sometable'
        yield SendMail(to, f_name, table )
```

you could then call it as:

```
for mailer in MailLoop():
    do_somthing_with_returned_status(mailer)
```